# how to write a simple server side script in aspx (c#)?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a php developer and I am trying to convert some php scripts (repeat scripts) to aspx. I am trying to make a simple upload script, pure server side (with separated html). This script has to save the file in the server and stop. In this example I cant declare functions.This is my not working script and I do not know why:

```
<%@ LANGUAGE ='C#' %>
<%
        string filePath = Server.MapPath(Request.QueryString["ax-file-path"]);
        string fileName = Request.QueryString["ax-file-name"];

        string allowExtstr  = Request.QueryString["ax-allow-ext"];
        string[] allowExt   = allowExtstr.Split('|');


        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath) && filePath.Length > 0)
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
        }

        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(thumbPath) && thumbPath.Length > 0)
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(thumbPath);
        }

        if(Request.Files.Count>0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; ++i)
            {
                HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[i];
                if(file.FileName!="")
                {
                    string fullPath = checkFilename(file.FileName, allowExt, filePath);
                    file.SaveAs(fullPath);
                    Response.Write(@"{""name"":"""+System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fullPath)+@""",""size"":""0"",""status"":""uploaded"",""info"":""File/chunk uploaded""}");
                }
            }
        }


        public string checkFilename(string filename, string[] allowExt, string filePath)
        {   
            string[] windowsReserved    = new string[] {"CON", "PRN", "AUX", "NUL","COM1", "COM2", "COM3", "COM4", "COM5", "COM6", "COM7", "COM8", "COM9",
                                    "LPT1", "LPT2", "LPT3", "LPT4", "LPT5", "LPT6", "LPT7", "LPT8", "LPT9"};    
            string[] badWinChars        = new string[] {"<", ">", ":", @"\", "/", "|", "?", "*"};

            for (int i = 0; i < badWinChars.Length; i++)
            {
                filename.Replace(badWinChars[i], "");        
            }
            string fileExt      = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filename);
            string fileBase     = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filename);

            //check if legal windows file name
            if(windowsReserved.Contains(fileBase))
            {
                Response.Write(@"{""name"":"""+fileBase+@""",""size"":""0"",""status"":""error"",""info"":""File name not allowed. Windows reserverd.""}");
                return "error";
            }

            //check if is allowed extension
            if(!allowExt.Contains(fileExt) && allowExt.Length>0)
            {
                Response.Write(@"{""name"":"""+fileBase+@""",""size"":""0"",""status"":""error"",""info"":""Extension "+fileExt+@" not allowed.""}");
                return "error";
            }

            string fullPath = filePath+fileBase;
            int c=0;
            while(System.IO.File.Exists(fullPath))
            {
                c++;
                fileBase= fileBase+"("+c+")."+fileExt;
                fullPath    = filePath+fileBase;
            }
            return fullPath;
        }
%>
```

And simple html code :

```
<form action="upload.aspx" method=post enctype=......>
<input type=file />
</form>
```

How should I write this code in correct way?

**EDIT:** I just want some, help. If this is not a good form of writing aspx c#, just tell me how to do it not that I write poor aspx code. I am a c#, php developer and have no experice in aspx, that's why I am asking

Comment: are you debugging? is there a specific exception?

Comment: Yes I debug, it is expecting a }, but is a strange error

Comment: fileBase= fileBase+"("+c.ToString()+")."+fileExt; this is not the problem, I just correct and nothing changed

Comment: <%@ Page Language="C#"> rather than <%@ Language="C#">??

Comment: <%@ Page Language="C#"> with this the error is in the first line, but the error remains at } before the checkName function

Comment: Try to remove <% in the second line and %> in the last line.

Comment: @will i am just asking how to resolve this problem (and may be learn how to write aspx.net) not what language is written stact or the poor form of aspx my programming. Can you help me?

Comment: @albanx: Nope.  I've written a few websites in both asp.net and asp.net mvc.  But I didn't *fight* the framework like you're doing.  Yes, you can use a claw hammer to turn a screw, but its meant to hammer nails in.

Comment: @Will if I want to fight the framework i would not write this scripts. I am a developer so one language from another is no different for me.

Comment: @albanx: This is the definition of fighting the framework.  Microsoft has dug a humongous pit of success in the .NET and surrounding frameworks.  You're trying to polevault over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution by my self. The trick was to split code in 2 files: one aspx file and one aspx.cs. the first is the file where i post upload from html, the second the class that handles upload. For those who have the same problem here is the source code:

**upload.aspx:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="upload.aspx.cs" Inherits="upload" %>
```

**upload.aspx.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.IO;
public partial class upload : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        string filePath = Server.MapPath(Request.QueryString["ax-file-path"]);
        string allowExtstr  = Request.QueryString["ax-allow-ext"];
        string[] allowExt   = allowExtstr.Split('|');


        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath) && filePath.Length > 0)
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
        }

        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(thumbPath) && thumbPath.Length > 0)
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(thumbPath);
        }

        if(Request.Files.Count>0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; ++i)
            {
                HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[i];
                string fullPath = checkFilename(file.FileName, allowExt, filePath);
                file.SaveAs(fullPath);
                Response.Write(@"{""name"":"""+System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fullPath)+@""",""size"":""0"",""status"":""uploaded"",""info"":""File/chunk uploaded""}");
            }
        }
    }

        public string checkFilename(string filename, string[] allowExt, string filePath)
        {   
            string[] windowsReserved    = new string[] {"CON", "PRN", "AUX", "NUL","COM1", "COM2", "COM3", "COM4", "COM5", "COM6", "COM7", "COM8", "COM9",
                                    "LPT1", "LPT2", "LPT3", "LPT4", "LPT5", "LPT6", "LPT7", "LPT8", "LPT9"};    
            string[] badWinChars        = new string[] {"<", ">", ":", @"\", "/", "|", "?", "*"};

            for (int i = 0; i < badWinChars.Length; i++)
            {
                filename.Replace(badWinChars[i], "");        
            }
            string fileExt      = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filename);
            fileExt = fileExt.Replace(".", "");
            string fileBase     = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filename);

            //check if legal windows file name
            if(Array.IndexOf(windowsReserved, fileBase)>=0)
            {
                Response.Write(@"{""name"":"""+fileBase+@""",""size"":""0"",""status"":""error"",""info"":""File name not allowed. Windows reserverd.""}");
                return "error";
            }

            //check if is allowed extension
            if (Array.IndexOf(allowExt, fileExt) < 0 && allowExt.Length > 0)
            {
                if (allowExt.Length != 1 || !String.Equals(allowExt[0], ""))
                {
                    Response.Write(@"{""name"":""" + fileBase + @""",""size"":" + allowExt[0] + @",""status"":""error"",""info"":""Extension " + fileExt + @" not allowed.""}");
                    return "error";
                }
            }

            string fullPath = filePath+fileBase;
            int c=0;
            while(System.IO.File.Exists(fullPath))
            {
                c++;
                fileBase= fileBase+"("+c.ToString()+")."+fileExt;
                fullPath    = filePath+fileBase;
            }
            return fullPath;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#">
<script runat="server">
   // your code
</script>
```

[web form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/015103yb.aspx)

Comment: It works only of do not declare functions, but just linear code

Comment: i was just looking at this http://www.chilkatsoft.com/p/p_534.asp maybe is what i need

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to inline the code in the page, why not put it in the codebehind page. This seems like perfect code to put in the page load of the page after a postback.

Comment: I do not really understand what you mean, but I just have to keep separated code from html code because the html page can post files to a php file but also to a aspx file.